# How to import large volume of data into CRM 2011 Online entities?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I need to import millions of records into a CRM 2011 Online entities. Is there any efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With CRM 2011 Online you have different ways:

- Use the standard `Import Data Wizard` functionality
- Use CRM Web Services to get the additional capabilities for import
  data, more details here: [Import Data in Microsoft Dynamics CRM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328321.aspx)
- Use CRM Web Services to build your own import tool using the new `ExecuteMultipleRequest`, more details here: [Use ExecuteMultiple to Improve Performance for Bulk Data Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj863631.aspx)
- Use an integration software as Scribe

Which one is more efficient between these methods depends on your crm structure, the source of your data, the complexity of the transformation, etc.

Comment: For millions of records I wouldn't touch the Import Wizard with a barge pole.  For efficiency, the new ExecuteMultipleRequest would be the way forward but it would depend on whether there is the coding knowledge around to do that.  Have any of the integration platforms (Scribe) started exploiting that yet?  Be good when they do.

Comment: John: Disclaimer: I work for one of those other companies (Simego). Our latest release can chew through 5000 per minute (Account) depending on entity. Account and contact have quite a bit of post processing behind them but you can get vey fast on custom entities. If you are have limited upload bandwidth it will choke in bulk mode.

Comment: If your importing many thousand(s) or million(s) of records then you also need to use parallel techniques with ExecuteMultipleRequest. using ExecuteMultipleRequest on a single thread might get you around 40 records/sec but with multiple threads we have seen as much as 500/sec to CRM Online 2013.

Comment: I know that this is old, but Sean 500 record a sec is pure insertion without resolving any lookup? Because as soon as i resolve a lookup everything chokes. The average time to get a guid is around 300ms so 500/sec for me is literally impossible. If i get to 5/sec with 2 lookups I considered myself luky (with 8 threads, if i add the update option too it will become really slow)

Comment: Also I tested the Execute multiple on update of records for 200 it takes around 8-9 seconds (always talking of online scenario).

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of other import tools for importing data [SSIS integration toolkit](http://www.kingswaysoft.com/) is one and [Import manager](http://www.crmextensions.com/?gclid=CIXp0Z3p4rYCFah8cAodVyUAWg) another

Answer (score 1):

We have a CRM migration tool that allows you to import data into CRM, both on-premise and online using the bulk import functionality which CRM provides.

Our product supports multiple table mappings per migration project, defining multiple data sources, and when you are done running your import in development, you can clone the connections into a new environment , for example SIT, UAT or PROD and re-run your import against there when ready. No coding required, so essentially anyone with BA / DB schema knowledge can use this tool to perform migration imports.

http://www.splsolutions.com.au

Any questions, please feel free to get in touch with us.

cheers,
Paul

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial might help. It shows how to send data stored in a SQL database to MSCRM 4.0 via CRM Web Services using SSIS.

The comments mention alternative options.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2008/05/07/integrating-crm-using-sql-integration-services-ssis.aspx