# How to change the default ExecuteMultipleRequest batch size limit in CRM 2011 on premise?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I encountered many errors like below in CRM 2011. I know there's a way to override the default value 1000. But how to?

> Error in workflow: ExecuteMultiple Request batch size exceeds the
>   maximum batch size allowed!

Comment: Rather break up the operation into more than one ExecuteMultipleRequest. ExecuteMultipleRequests can time out after 2 minutes even with under 1000 records. See one approach [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229307/import-multiple-records-into-crm)

Answer (score 3):

You can change the setting via PoweShell using `UpdateAdvancedSettingsRequest` - examples see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a4061cd-e6b4-4672-8c44-20a27c523718#use_powershell_advanced).

Further details about settings can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309371.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334634.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. I see there's a "Get-CrmAdvancedSetting" cmdlet. But it only works on local machine. How to run it against a remote CRM server?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have access to a CRM server currently - so I can't try it myself to give a definitve answer :-(

Answer (score 2):

For CRM On Premise, you could execute the following SQL Command directly at the MSCRM_CONFIG database (at your own risk):

```
update deploymentproperties set IntColumn = *"your value here"* where columnname = 'ExecuteMultipleMaxBatchSize'
```

It takes a while for the changes to be applied. Alternatively, you can restart the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Services