# xrm sdk ExecuteMultipleRequest transaction with rollback

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

I have a large number of records that I need to add to my CRM database.

I am using the following code:

```cs
var emRequest = new ExecuteMultipleRequest {
    Requests = entityCreateRequests,
    Settings = new ExecuteMultipleSettings
    {
        ContinueOnError = true,
        ReturnResponses = true
    }
};
var createResponse = (ExecuteMultipleResponse)serviceProxy.Execute(emRequest);
```

Because of the large number of records, I have to split the total number of `entityCreateRequests` into batches of 500. Now I know that if one of those in the batch of 500 fails, the whole batch fails, which is what good for me.
However, I would like to do a transaction for ALL my records, even if I have to do it one by one. Something similar to a transaction in Entity Framework, like so:

```cs
serviceProxy.begin();
for (i =0 ; i<totalTrans; i++) {
    try {
        var createResponse = (ExecuteMultipleResponse)serviceProxy.Execute(emRequest);
    }
    catch(e) {
        serviceProxy.rollback();
        break;
    }
    serviceProxy.commit();
}
```

Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You could (and probably should) use an unbound **Action** to handle the creates. You could for example have an Action 'CreateMultipleAccounts' that has an EntityCollection as Input parameter.

In this Action, you'd need a workflow assembly that iterates over the EntityCollection and creates the records. You could also simply execute an ExecuteMultipleRequest in this workflow assembly.

The biggest benefit to this is that Actions are executed as a single transaction, meaning that if a create/update should fail, the entire process will be rolled back.

Make sure that you check the **Enable Rollback** checkbox ofcourse.

Edit: There's a blogpost by Aileen Gusni that describes this actual scenario and her test results, which you can find at https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/misscrm360exploration/archive/2015/07/05/utilizing-crm-custom-action-for-transaction-rollback-purposes.

Comment: This is very interesting. I will have to spend some time on it to learn how to use it and test it out. In the mean time, should I mark your answer as correct and just post another question if this does not solve the problem (or creates new issues)?

Comment: You should only mark your question as answered if my response actually answered/solved your question, I'd personally leave it open for the moment... but that's just my opinion though.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly you basically want to link the several `ExecuteMultipleRequests` together to a single request. I don't think that what you have in mind is possible.

You can however update the MaxBatchSize, see here: [How to change the default ExecuteMultipleRequest batch size limit in CRM 2011 on premise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18265343/how-to-change-the-default-executemultiplerequest-batch-size-limit-in-crm-2011-on)

Alternatively on a create only you could store the result and manually revert the creation by removing them on a fail of a later request.

```cs
var idList = new List<Guid>();
var emRequest = new ExecuteMultipleRequest
{
    Requests = new OrganizationRequestCollection(),
    Settings = new ExecuteMultipleSettings
    {
        ContinueOnError = false,
        ReturnResponses = true
    },
};

var executeMultipleResponse = (ExecuteMultipleResponse)service.Execute(emRequest);
if (!executeMultipleResponse.IsFaulted)
{
    foreach (var response in executeMultipleResponse.Responses)
    {
        if (!response.Response.Results.Contains("id"))
            continue;

        var idValue = (string)response.Response.Results["id"];
    }
}
else
{
    foreach (var id in idList)
    {
        service.Delete("entitylogicalname", id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly how I am handling it now. I just don't like it because I had to build the safeguard where I am pretty sure there is a more elegant way of doing so.